# Linuxの環境変数に関するドキュメント

Tags: linux, man

Linuxで環境変数に関して調べる方法について教えてください。

質問1) manやinfoは、主にLinuxのコマンドについて調べられると思うのですが、環境変数についてもまとまった情報があるのでしょうか？

質問2) 環境変数について調べるとUbuntuのWikiに、Environment Variableというページがありました。こちらは、Ubuntuで独自に用意したドキュメントかと思うのですが、Linuxとして参照するドキュメントは別にあるのでしょうか？

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### man

man ページ は、

```bash
man environ
```

です。

#### ドキュメント

一般に、（カーネルではない）ユーザースペースに関して、ディストリビューション中立かつ公式的な位置付けの「Linuxとして参照するドキュメント」は、[The Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) 以外に無いと思います。最近は、Arch Linux の Wiki が充実しており、ディストリビューション固有の記述も少なめなので、よく参照されます。
参考: [環境変数](https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E5%A4%89%E6%95%B0)

Unix 全般ということですと、POSIX があります。
参考: [Environment Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)

Answer (score 3):

直接の回答ではありませんが必要そうなので…。

> Ubuntuで独自に用意したドキュメントかと思うのですが、Linuxとして参照するドキュメント

大前提として「Linux」という特定のOSは存在しません。例えば`ls`を実行しますが、これは概ね[GNU core utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)というツールがインストールされているだけです。WebサーバーにApacheを使ったりしますがもちろん[The Apache Software Foundation](https://httpd.apache.org/)の成果物です。

このようにいわゆるLinuxはすべてのプログラムが別の作者によるものであり、ごった煮の寄せ集めであることを認識する必要があります。それらを集めてOSとして仕立て上げたのが、UbuntuでありRed Hat Linuxとなります。
真にLinuxとしての成果物は[Linux Kernel](https://www.kernel.org/)のみとなり、[そのドキュメントもカーネルに関するもののみ](https://docs.kernel.org/)となります。

---

期待する回答ではないとも思いますが、カーネルはプロセスや環境変数を管理する機能は持ちますが、自身はプロセスではなく環境変数も持ちません。そのため、Linuxとして環境変数が定められているわけではありません。

また、先述の通り、個々のプログラムにはそれぞれの作者がいます。個々のプログラムが扱う環境変数についてもそれぞれの作者の判断で実装されているだけであり、統一された環境変数の定義はありません（レアケースですが、同じ環境変数を別の用途に使われる可能性もあります）。